# Does every chain of parentNodes terminate?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser, directed-acyclic-graphs

Will the following JavaScript function terminate for any DOM element? Or can the DOM contain a cycle of elements (for example, a node which is its own parentNode's parentNode)?

```
function walkUpDom(elt) {
  while (elt.parentNode) {
    elt = elt.parentNode;
  }
  return elt;
}
```

Comment: It will bubble up until it reaches the root element. (document for browsers)

Comment: @fblundun.... the parentNode() function will definitely terminate on reaching the root of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentNode property returns the parent node of the specified node, as a Node object.

I don't think there is any point of using `while` here.

Also a node can never be its own parentNode's parentNode. I can not think of any such case!